# I really can not stop the handler! How can I?

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable

I've googled already, and all topics say the same solution `handler.removeCallbacks(null)` or `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`. But none of them worked for me.

```
Handler handler;
Runnable runnable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    //...

    handler = new Handler();

    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            time -= 100;
            if(time == 0){
                Intent i = new Intent(Question.this, WrongAnswer.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
            else{
                handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable,3000);

    //...
}
```

And here is the case where the activity exits before the time runs out:

```
if(myAnswer == correctAnswer)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, CorrectAnswer.class);
    startActivity(i);
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Use handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) instead.

Comment: i have tried using handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) but the same problem appears

Comment: Your handler keeps running even though you call finish in the runnable? Won't that stop the current activity?

Comment: First I run the intent to switch to another activity, then i use handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) to stop the handler, but in my case it isnt working. Then I use the finish() to exit the previous activity.

Comment: may be something occurs because of the intent. As far as I have seen on other posts they were not using intents

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your runnable global before `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)` would work. Also, you can use a global variable for checking if you cancelled already (this is just for safety)

```
private boolean isCancelled = false;
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isCancelled)    return;
        time -= 100;
        if(time == 0){
            Intent i = new Intent(Question.this, WrongAnswer.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else{
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    }
};
```

and then:

```
isCancelled = true;
handler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
```

Comment: I think that handler and runnable are already global, because I declared them before onCreate methon. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try the isCancelled boolean?

Comment: yep i did its not working, probably cause i finish() the activity and the variable is destroyed.i dont know.

Comment: I fixed this issue using the principle of the isCanceled boolean but instead i store that data in SharedPreferences and its working good, the bug is fixed